# Codeigniter form validation alpha

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, alpha

So i have question with codeigniter. In form validation, alpha means only a, b, c and so on... But what i must do if in my language is alphabet that not aloved by alpha fomr validation? Codeigniter not letting my write that simbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [callback function](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) that validates special characters in addition to a-z.